# String not outputting the characters i type in

Tags: c++

so this program is supposed to input things i type in, and output them in a matrix format, heres the code i have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define N 6


//
// fill:
//
void fill(string s, int M[][N], int ROWS, int COLS)
{
int i, r, c;

for (i=0, r=0; r < ROWS; r++)
{
    for (c=0; c < COLS; c++)
    {
  M[r][c] = s[i];  // store ith character into matrix:

  i++;  // next character:
  if (i == s.length())  // start-over if that was last char:
    i = 0;
    }
}
 }

void print(int M[][N], int ROWS, int COLS)
{

string s;
getline(cin,s);
    int r, c;
for(r=0; r< ROWS; r++)
{
for(c=0; c < COLS; c++)
{


cout<<(char)M[r][c];


}

 cout <<endl; 
}
}
//
// main:
//
int main()
{
string s;
int  M[N][N];
int  M2[N][N];
int  row, col, ROWS, COLS;


ROWS = sizeof(M) / sizeof(M[0]);
COLS = sizeof(M[0]) / sizeof(M[0][0]);

fill(s, M, 1, 1);
print(M, ROWS, COLS);

return 0;
}
```

any idea why its outputting random characters out instead of the ones i type in?

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not initializing string s before passing it to fill function.
Next, you are trying to insert a string into an int. C++ doesn't let you do that directly.

Are you trying to split a string such as "123456" into [1,2,3,4,5,6; 1,2,3,4,5,6;...] etc?
Is this what you want your program to do?

Comment: yes so that whatever i type in comes out as 6 characters in the first line and carries over to the next one and so on

Comment: If your input **must** be a string, use atoi function to convert it from string "123456" to and int 123456. Then keep taking remainder with 10 to get each digit of this number. You can take remainder with 10 using the mod '%' operator.

Comment: sorry im mostly new to these types of programs so i dont know what that means

Answer (score 0):

Here you are storing the input in an integer array and trying to display the character values.

The statement cout<<(char)M[r][c] will give you the ASCII value corresponding to the integer value of M[r][c].

That might be the random characters you are seeing.
You can directly use a character array instead and try outputing by directly calling:cout<< M[r][c]

Comment: when i output them directly however it gives me numbers, i need to output to be the letters i type out

Comment: Pass a character array char M[][N] instead of the integer array you are using in the functions print and fill and then do the direct output.

Comment: i just tried that, in the program im using that does not work

Comment: What I meant is make the following changes in your functions:    void fill(string s, char M[][N], int ROWS, int COLS) and   void print(char M[][N], int ROWS, int COLS).

Comment: thats what i tried and then the code stips working completely

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

    using namespace std;

    #define N 6

    void fill(string s, char (&arr)[N][N])
    {
        int char_index =0;
        for (int i=0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j < N; j++)
            {
                arr[i][j] = s.at(char_index);           
                if (char_index+1 == s.size()){
                    char_index =0;
                }else{
                    char_index++;
                }               
            }
        }   
    }

    void print(char arr[][N])
    {
        cout << "--------------" << endl;
        int char_index =0;
        for (int i=0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j < N; j++)
            {
                cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "--------------" << endl;

    }

    int main()
    {
        string s ="";
        cout << "Enter your string:";
        getline(cin,s); 
        char M[N][N];
        fill(s,M);
        print(M);
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```